# OpenERP v7 -> Issue when deleting many2many_tags. Deleted but still on screen

Tags: odoo

I've one "taxes" field in sale.order.line where it is rendered using many2many_tags. Basically, when we add a tag and then focus out, the value of the tag seems to be add in the field.
When I want to delete the tag, I click on the field, I see the box tag with its value and cross to delete it. Clicking on the cross delete the tag BUT when I focus out the value is still in the field...

I checked in openerp js sources but found nothing probant...

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to an inappropriate IF condition in openerp-web-7.0/addons/web/static/src/js/view_list.js near line 1048:

```
if (value instanceof Array && !_.isEmpty(value)
                    && !record.get(column.id + '__display'))
```

Before adding m2m tag the '__display' attribute doesn't exist, so the condition passes succesfully. However, if you had a second tag, the '__display' attribute does exist, thus condition is false and the next part of the code updating document can't be done.

You need to override it and add another condition to check whether '__display' already exists.